# Click to drag simultaneous vertical and horizontal scroll for web

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, drag

tl;dr I'm wondering if it's possible to have the mouse move a webpage like google maps. And if it is possible, what's the basic idea of how I would do this?

I'm currently planning out a website and one of the ideas I had was to let the user click and drag to move in 2 dimensions. This experience would be similar to google maps, where you click and drag to move in the space.

I've seen some snippets of code that allow you to scroll horizontally with your mouse, but I can't find anything that allows you to do both horizontal and vertical at the same time.

And tips or idea on how this can be achieved is appreciated.

Comment: If you've tried something that didn't work, please do post your code here in a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. The idea is to use `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` events. What happens with your page depends on the container you use. Google Maps, for example, uses `<canvas>` to display maps.